# my notebook NP-N130 won't start up

Tags: windows-7, windows

When I turn on my notebook, it just keeps saying

> Operating system not found

What do I need to do to fix it? It's a NP-N130 Samsung notebook

Comment: Some more details would be nice. What did you do before this happened? Does the original OS drive show up off a livecd?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is no DVD, floppy disk, ZIP disk or whatsoever in your drives when you boot your system.

Should you laptop refuse to boot anyway and this seems to have happened out of the sudden, this might indicate your hard disk failure. You'll need to have your HDD exchanged and install the OS anew. There are chances that you can also restore some data from your corrupted drive, but this can be done only be a trained professional.

Comment: I can't remember ever actually seeing a zip disk in the wild

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: The firm I used to work for sold thousands of the systems (both laptop and desktop) with IOmega ZIP drive in Germany. So I do have really seen many of those, even though I never used them on my own...